# How to fit a flex container inside a grid container

Tags: reactjs, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to fit in a flex container with margins on both sides inside a grid container, but at the smallest viewport width the flex container leaks out. I have added borders to the respective divs to show where its leaking.

I have also added a demo to show my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/9z49m3ny0p

If the demo isn't clear, take a look at these screenshots:

[image: Lowest viewport] [image: Medium viewport]

*As you see from the above screenshots, that the red border stays within the viewport at all times but the blue bordered container spills out.*

**Home.js**

```
<div id="rightContainer">
    <div id="editorContainer">
        <Notepad />
    </div>
    <div id="notesCardContainer">
        <NoteCard />
        <NoteCard />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Home.css**

```
#editorContainer {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#notesCardContainer {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

And **Notepad.js** :

```
<div className="editorInnerContainer">
    <div className="editorTop">
        <input
         type="text"
         id="noteTitle"
         value="Some Title"
         disabled={true}
        />
        <div id="tools">
            <a href="" title="Edit this note">
                <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt" />
            </a>
            <a href="" title="Delete this note">
                <i className="fas fa-trash" />
            </a>
            <a href="" title="Download this note">
                <i className="fas fa-download" />
            </a>
            <a href="" title="Share this note">
                <i className="fas fa-share-square" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Snippet from Notepad.css**

```
.editorInnerContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: var(--white-100);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/2v0o67w4kn

```
#noteTitle {
    flex: 1;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: none;
    color: var(--black);
    border: 2px solid sandybrown;

    /* add width */
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to adjust the border issue as well, set the width to 100% - the border sizes added together via calc: https://codesandbox.io/s/l7rk0zop69

```
#noteTitle {
    width: calc(100% - 6px);
    max-width: calc(100% - 6px);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, the first works correctly on FF, but there is till an issue in Chrome. I have to manually refresh the page after resize to get it properly.

Comment: Weird, you mean when you resize the editors preview window? I do not have that issue in chrome. However when I just checked it seems it calculates the border with 4px instead of 6 (which also makes more sense since both seem 2px wide).

Comment: Yep, I am testing it on my browser, not on the sandbox. On chrome only, when I load the page, everything is fine, I resized it and the red border along with its content moved out a bit to the right. I refreshed it, and it came back within the viewport.

Comment: What a weird issue. Have you tried adding box-sizing: border-box to the boxes?

Comment: Yes, have added box-sizing to the red bordered container. But nothing happened

Comment: This strange issue happens only in chrome

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue in my chrome (after adding box-sizing: border-box) https://i.imgur.com/S6jNmIi.png and https://i.imgur.com/8lZHwR3.png I am using Version 66.0.3359.139

Comment: Am on the same chrome version but can't understand why the problem is occurring for me.

Comment: On which elements did you add box-sizing?

Comment: Ok, without box-sizing its working only if I manually resize the browser width. Else if I click on the browser's resize button that issue occurs.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue with the maximize button on chrome, but not for manual resizing. I would recommend opening a new question for this specific issue, maybe someone else might have a solution or some input for this issue :)

Comment: Sure will do. Thanks for the help :)